# Parse CloudCode getting Users from Array

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have an object in my Parse DB called `Post` with the following attributes.

```
Post
--------
Author   - a Parse.User object
Text     - just a string
Mentions - an array of Parse.User objects
```

I've written some `afterSave` cloud code like so...

I'm trying to get the users out of the mentions array so that I can send push notifications to them.  However, in the after save function I just can't get hold of them.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Post", function(request) {
    console.log("Blah, just checking I'm here.");
});
```

The logs say...

```
{
    "author": {
        "objectId":"asdfasdf",
        "className":"_User",
        "__type":"Pointer"
    },
    "text":"1",
    "location":{
        "longitude":-1,234565,
        "latitude":50.12345,
        "__type":"GeoPoint"
    },
    "createdAt":"2014-04-30T15:07:43.874Z",
    "updatedAt":"2014-04-30T15:07:43.874Z",
    "objectId":"sdfgsdf",
    "ACL":{
        "*":{
            "read":true
        },
        "asdfasdf":{
            "write":true,
            "read":true
        }
    }
}
```

There is no mention of the `mentions` array at all.

When I check with the data browser the mentions array is added properly. I just can't seem to find it.

Any ideas what I can do to get this?

Comment: How does the log print this? Is something missing in your question?

Comment: @Handsomeguy No, nothing missing. The "input object" of every custom `afterSave` function is printed in the logs by default.

Comment: Where's that Javascript output from? You're logging out `request.object`?

Comment: @JamesFrost No, the log comes from just overriding the `afterSave` function. I changed to do it on `beforeSave` and it does include the `mentions` array but would prefer to do it on `afterSave`. If I log out `request.object` then I get `[Object object]`. If I log `request.object.get("mentions")` then I get `undefined`.

Comment: Can you show how you're constructing and saving the Post? Also are you doing anything else in your beforeSave?